How can I redirect a publicly-accessible port without allowing the target port to also be publicly accessible?
I have a web server running as non-root Debian Linux kernel 6.1.x on port :8443. I'd like to allow clients to connect over :443, so I'm using iptables for that purpose:
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443

I've found that this does not work as expected unless I also add this:
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT

I've tried combinations of -o if and -i if on the INPUT --dport 8443 rule but they all seem to leave the service unreachable.
Is there any way to disallow port 8443 access to the public interface (eth0 in this case) but allow this port-mangling to continue?

disallow port 8443 access to the public interface why? the service is exposed anyway.

Seems like a good idea to me!

@user10489 while I don't really see the point, you can additionally redirect traffics originally destined at 8443 to 443, assuming the idea is to make the service inaccessible through 8443 (but only 443), and depends on what you want, you may as well drop or reject those traffics (that now destined at 433) in INPUT. (Or you may directly drop traffics originally destined at 8443 in mangle/PREROUTING.)

Set up nginx and let it act as a reverse proxy? This is a fairly common thing to do with it.

@TomYan Yes I kind of agree it make no functional difference. I would simply like to have fewer ports responding.

@muru Set up a reverse proxy just for this one thing? It's a waste of resources, makes the environment more complicated, and introduces a new potential attack vector.

Well, nobody's stopping you from another thing as well. Are you running on some sort of minimal embedded system? If not, the resource impact of nginx is pretty minimal. I used to run it on my Pi 3B for years (and now on a 4B for years) and nginx definitely wasn't giving the Pi any stress. If anything, a well-tested, made-for-purpose HTTP server like nginx or lighthttpd run in a minimal configuration is going to be more secure than directly exposing than something like, say gunicorn, directly to the internet.
